# Differentiation involving vector variables

Tags: multivariable-calculus, optimization, convex-optimization, duality-theorems, hessian-matrix

I am learning Lagrangian duality methods in an optimization course.

Below is from my lecture note.

> Let $\ell(\textbf{x}; \lambda) =-x_1x_2+\lambda[(x_1-3)^2+x^2_2-5]$.
>
> Then, the Hessian of $\ell(\textbf{x}; \lambda)$ is
>
> $ 
>    \nabla^2\ell(\textbf{x}; \lambda) =
>   \left[ {\begin{array}{cc}
>    2\lambda & -1 \\
>    -1 & 2\lambda \\
>   \end{array} } \right]
>  $

To give you more context of the problem, $\space\phi(\lambda) =$ Min$\ell(\textbf{x};\lambda)$ is the dual function.

Since $\textbf{x}$ is a column vector with 2 variables $x_1$ and $x_2$, I think the hessian should be a 3 by 3 matrix.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: You get that matrix by keeping $ \lambda $ constant and differentiating $ - x _ 1 x _ 2 + \lambda [ ( x _ 1 - 3 ) ^ 2 + x _ 2 ^ 2 - 5 ] $ twice with respect to $ x _ 1 $ and $ x _ 2 $.  So rather than treating $ \mathbf x $ as a scalar, I think that they're treating $ \lambda $ as a constant. (Also, you'll need $ \ell ( \mathbf x ; \lambda ) $ to be $ - x _ 1 x _ 2 + \lambda [ ( x _ 1 - 3 ) ^ 2 + x _ 2 ^ 2 - 5 ] $ itself, rather than the minimum of that, which isn't a function of $ \mathbf x $ and $ \lambda $ at all.)

Comment: @TobyBartels Thank you for your insights. I think you are right. I will edit the part about minimum. However, I am still not sure why we are treating $\lambda$ as a constant.

Comment: I would suggest avoiding using $\nabla^2$ to denote the Hessian. I would suggest using either $\mathbf H$ or simply $\nabla\nabla$.

Comment: With the context that you're looking at $ \phi ( \lambda ) $ as a function of $ \lambda $ alone, I think that I can see why.  I'll write this up as an answer.

Comment: @K.defaoite I copied it from my lecture note, but I will mark your words. Why do you not recommend using the $\nabla^2$ notation?

Comment: @hnbm Because it is generally taken to mean the Laplacian, $\nabla^2=\sum_k \frac{\partial^2}{\partial {x_k}^2}$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since $ \ell $ is a function of $ 3 $ variables, it's true that $ \nabla ^ 2 \ell ( \mathbf x ; \lambda ) $ is really a $ 3 $-by-$ 3 $ matrix, specifically $$ \left [ \matrix { 2 \lambda & - 1 & 2 ( x _ 1 - 3 ) \\ - 1 & 2 \lambda & 2 x _ 2 \\ 2 ( x _ 1 - 3 ) & 2 x _ 2 & 0 } \right ] \text . $$  However, in finding $ \phi ( \lambda ) : = \min _ { \mathbf x } \ell ( \mathbf x ; \lambda ) $, you're not really minimizing the function $ \ell $, but rather minimizing a function of $ \mathbf x $ alone.  If we write $ \ell _ \lambda ( \mathbf x ) : = \ell ( \mathbf x ; \lambda ) $, then $ \ell _ \lambda $ is a function of only $ 2 $ variables, and $ \nabla ^ 2 \ell _ \lambda ( \mathbf x ) $ is the the $ 2 $-by-$ 2 $ matrix $$ \left [ \matrix { 2 \lambda & - 1 \\ - 1 & 2 \lambda } \right ] $$ that you have in your notes.  Since $ \ell _ \lambda $ is the relevant function to analyse to find $ \phi $, this is the relevant Hessian matrix.  (And the relevant gradient to set to $ \mathbf 0 $ is $ \nabla \ell _ \lambda ( \mathbf x ) = [ - x _ 2 + 2 \lambda ( x _ 1 - 3 ) , - x _ 1 + 2 \lambda x _ 2 ] $.  Also notice that this only actually gives you a minimum when $ \lambda > 0 $.)

Comment: I see. Since we are minimizing $\ell(\textbf{x};\lambda)$ subject to $x_1$ and $x_2$ only, we treat $\lambda$ as a constant like how we do partial differentiation and find the hessian with $x_1$ and $x_2$. Thanks Toby!

Comment: Exactly, the Hessian is a kind of second derivative, and the Hessian of $\ell_\lambda$ is a partial Hessian of $\ell$.  You're welcome!